# How should I correct ill-formatted lat-long pairs to be valid for PHP computation

Tags: php, regex, latitude-longitude

I have access to a dataset that contains latitude and longitude pairs, but they are ill formatted and are not properly represented in the data set.

For example, a lat-long pair might look like this: `31333445, 105530865` when it *should* be `31.333445, -105.530865`. Given the data set I am working with I know that the min value for latitude is `31.0` and the max is `37.0`, and the min/max of longitude is `-103` to `-109`.

If I was given a piece of paper and a pencil I could easily correct these myself, but the correction needs to happen on the fly when we receive input from a different program. We have no control over how the data is formatted until it hits our system and then we can make changes and corrections, and the lat-long pairs are all in a integer format listed above rather than a float.

What would be the best way to go about manually correcting this error? I am using PHP for our processing system.

Comment: Wlil the number of digits be always the same fixed size? then use the solution suggested by @AbraCadaver.

Comment: `are not properly represented in the data set` ... possibly there *is* data in the "meta" on how to transform this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Are there any more obscure formattings, or are all lines in the same format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If they're the same length then just divide by `1000000` and make negative where needed:

```
echo $lat / 1000000;
echo -$lon / 1000000;
```

If not then get the number of numbers at the start (2 and 3 here) making negative if needed, then insert a decimal and the remaining:

```
echo substr($lat, 0, 2) . '.' . substr($lat, 2);
echo -substr($lon, 0, 3) . '.' . substr($lon, 3);
```

You can use `floatval()` on the results if needed.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in replying and accepting an answer. The system standardizes the lat-long data lengths, so this solution worked quite nicely.

Answer (score 1):

If the number of digits is always the same fixed size then use the solution suggested by @AbraCadaver in his comment  ( just divide by 1000000 and multiply with -1)

If the number of digits can be different you need a different solution
and I have got a weird idea (at 0:24am)

```
I would convert the number to a string   resulting in "31333445"
then  concatenate "0." with the "31333445" resulting in  "0.31333445"
then convert it back to a double   resulting in 0.31333445
and then multiply it with 100 resulting in 31.333445 (and multiply the other value with -1 )
```

:-B

With this solution it does  not matter if the  number you get from outside  has 3 or 14 digits
May sound weird but should work.

If this sounds to be a useful solution i will put into code tomorrow.